# Python RegEx: how to replace each match individually

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a string `s`, a pattern `p` and a replacement `r`, i need to get the list of strings in which only one match with `p` has been replaced with `r`.

Example:

```py
s = 'AbcAbAcc'
p = 'A'
r = '_'

// Output:
['_bcAbAcc', 'Abc_bAcc', 'AbcAb_cc']
```

I have tried with `re.finditer(p, s)` but i couldn't figure out how to replace each match with `r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace them manually after finding all the matches:

```
[s[:m.start()] + r + s[m.end():] for m in re.finditer(p,s)]
```

The result is:

```
['_bcAbAcc', 'Abc_bAcc', 'AbcAb_cc']
```

---

How does it work?

- `re.finditer(p,s)` will find all matches (each will be a `re.Match`
  object)
- the `re.Match` objects have `start()` and `end()` method which return the location of the match
- you can replace the part of string between begin and end using this code: `s[:begin] + replacement + s[end:]`

Comment: Suggest using `m.start()` instead of `m.span()[0]` and `m.end()` instead of `m.span()[1]`.

Comment: @RootTwo: Absolutely. Thanks. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this, it's as simple as

```
[s[:i]+r+s[i+1:] for i,c in enumerate(s) if c==p]
```

Full code: [See it working here](https://tio.run/##Hcc9CoAwDEDhPafIVqUu4iZ06DlKEQ0VM1hLWkFPX3@m9710l@2IQ60ZDSq7kF0skYL0rwL5OimA64XLbmSvRWfHuh89rocgd4QcMcRzDzKX0OQWeUUyJnlIwrE0V1vrAw)

```
s = 'AbcAbAcc'
p = 'A'
r = '_'

x = [s[:i]+r+s[i+1:] for i,c in enumerate(s) if c==p]
print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
['_bcAbAcc', 'Abc_bAcc', 'AbcAb_cc']
```

---

As mentioned, this only works on one character, for anything longer than one character or requiring a regex, use [zvone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59313152/3600709).

For a performance comparison between mine and zvone's answer (plus a third method of doing this without regex), see [here](https://tio.run/##hZDBaoUwEEXXzVfMzgRF6nMnuPA7JBSNYzvQxDDJg/brbaKPUlqkgXBnyL0HbvxnfNtcu@9k/cYRIlmkWDEKEaCHYpjNMA/GFMIfayE460shxIIrfDRSdeKJMd7ZwRjGjnTJZRipbDoN68ZAlQFygO5ukaeIMiigFUzfe/2A3P6HZARP7hXlO7qEOBjJoX9g2t8YW4c4cZRKQwmcbhhtjW5JvhNrDyzWK7mFIrL0VVAJ55lclLmcesznv9SnpJcKUp8ZuW@e8/n25S4Xmdtlpr3MtH8y@/4F) or test it yourself with the code below:

```
import timeit,re

s = 'AbcAbAcc'
p = 'A'
r = '_'

def x1():
    return [s[:i]+r+s[i+1:] for i,c in enumerate(s) if c==p]

def x2():
    return [s[:i]+r+s[i+1:] for i in range(len(s)) if s[i]==p]

def x3():
    return [s[:m.start()] + r + s[m.end():] for m in re.finditer(p,s)]

print(x1())
print(timeit.timeit(x1, number=100000))
print(x2())
print(timeit.timeit(x2, number=100000))
print(x3())
print(timeit.timeit(x3, number=100000))
```

Comment: That's only true if `p` is always one character long, but for what i need `p` is going to be an actual pattern. But yes with the example I provided that's going to work perfectly!

Comment: Easy to extend to many characters long. x = [s[:m] + r + s[m+len(p):] for m in findall(s, p)]